# Scala Generic Type as Class Parameter and matching (& Slick)

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I'm trying to understand how to pass a type parameter to a class during pattern matching and have it implied for the subsequent method (not a part of the class being matched on), like so:

class:

```
case class QueryRequest[A](data: List[A])
```

pattern match:

```
def receive = {

    case QueryRequest(data) => sender ! QueryResponse(setScanRecords(data))
...
}
```

method:

```
 def setScanRecords[A](data: List[A]) = 
     db withTransaction { data foreach ScanRecords.insert }
```

Type `A` will be a tuple of variable composition, for example:

```
(String, String, Long)
```

or

```
(String, String, String, String)
```

etc.

What's the best way to do this?  Currently `setScanRecords` throws the following exception:

`type mismatch;  found   : [TT](query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[TT,(String, String, Long)])(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Int <and> (value: (String, String, Long))(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Int  required: A => ?`

**Edit1:**

To elaborate, another type of error occurs when I explicitly call out the type in the method in the method call:

method:

```
def setScanRecords(data: List[(String, String, Long)]) = 
     db withTransaction { data foreach ScanRecords.insert }
```

error:

```
case QueryRequest(data) => sender ! QueryResponse(setScanRecords(data))
```

`type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: List[(String, String, Long)]`

Comment: Instead of having one type parameter for `QueryRequest` and one for `setScanRecords`, can you factor it by moving it up to an enclosing class/trait? Can you perhaps make your actor class generic?

Comment: How is `InsertQueryRequest` defined? Like `QueryRequest`?

Comment: @Qerub, Copy/Paste/Simplification error.  I've corrected it above.  InsertQueryRequest = QueryRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pattern matching `data` in `setScanRecords` in order to make sure the type / data being passed to the function conformed to the database insert criteria.

```
def setScanRecords[A](data: List[A]) =
    db withTransaction {
      data foreach {
        case (a: String, b: String, c: Long) => ScanRecords.insert(a, b, c)
        case s => throw new Exception(s"Expected (String, String, Long) but found something else: $s")
      }
    }
```

Until I find a more elegant solution, I've gone this route.

Answer (score 0):

messages received in `receive` method have no type informations.

Doing pattern matching is to get the message of the types you want to deal with (which is a list of Tuple`N`) in order to use the `message` in the following expressions.
But, in `InsertQueryRequest(data)`, the type is still uncertain, which causes the error.

Maybe, you can send the `data` along with the tuple type message.

And I wonder how `db` insert records without knowing the tuple`N` is.